# NetTopologySuite reverse a polygon to have it CCW

Tags: c#, gis, nettopologysuite

I have added a check to identify if the polygon coords are in the wrong order and if the condition is verified I want to fix it, but I get that the Reverse() function is deprecated:

```
List<Coordinate> polygonCoords = new List<Coordinate>();
foreach(LatLngDto latlng in latlngs.LatLngs)
{
    Coordinate vertex = new Coordinate(latlng.Lng, latlng.Lat);
    polygonCoords.Add(vertex);
}
polygonCoords.Add(new Coordinate(latlngs.LatLngs[0].Lng, latlngs.LatLngs[0].Lat));

var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
var customShape = geometryFactory.CreatePolygon(polygonCoords.ToArray());

if (!customShape.Shell.IsCCW)
{
    customShape = (Polygon)customShape.Reverse();
}

List<int> gridCellCodes = (from gc in grid5KmCellRepo.GetAll()
                        where gc.Grid5KmCellCoords.Intersects(customShape)
                        select gc.Grid5KmCellId).ToList();
```

What should I use?

I haven't found any relevant documentation on NetTopologySuite and the method is still in their documentation:
https://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite/api/NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry.html#NetTopologySuite_Geometries_Geometry_Reverse

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overload `Polygon.Reverse()` is obsolete, the base implementation `Geometry.Reverse()` is not.

```
customShape = (Polygon)(((Geometry)customShape).Reverse());
```

should make the `Obsolete` warning go away.